# How to fire an API whenever a variable changes?

Tags: angular

I already have the below code to change myVariable

```
private dataSubscription: Subscription;
myVariable: number;

this.dataSubscription = this.mydata.onReply$.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.myVariable = data.id;
});
```

But I want to fire the below API whenever there is a change in `myVariable`. How can i detect that `'myVariable'` has changed and fire the API?

```
this.myService.getMyFunction(this.myVariable).subscribe((data) => {
    this.tobeUpdated = data;            
)};
```

I think it is simple but I'm new to angular and i need help in this. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Where else this variable can be changed? Or only in `observable`?

Comment: Instead of storing the id in a 'number' variable, store it in an RxJs 'BehaviorSubject' object. You will then be able to subscribe to the changes. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Only in Observable.

Comment: @Ploppy I'm checking for some plunker example. Let me try..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check the value of myVariable when you are assiging it. If the value is changed, emit another event that will fire your getMyFunction

```
private dataSubscription: Subscription;

this.dataSubscription = this.mydata.onReply$.subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (this.myVariable !== data.id) {                 
        this.myVariable = data.id;
        this.variableChanged.emit(true);
    }
});
```

Now over here

```
variableChanged.subscribe(data => {
    this.myService.getMyFunction(this.myVariable).subscribe((data) => {
        this.tobeUpdated = data;            
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell how to define variableChanged?

Comment: For defining event emitter, i added like this topicUpdated = new EventEmitter<number>();